# Unable to retrive value from body of request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am passing api request in postman like this

```
{
    "q":"delhi ncr"
}
```

And my api looks like this

```
app.get('/locations', async (req, res) => {
  const query = req.body.q;
  console.log(req.body);
  const data = await zomato.cities({ q: String(query),count: 1 })

  res.send(data);
}
```

The console log returns `{}` I don't know where I am going wrong here. If I hard code some string value to q it works, but not like this.

[image: postman request]

Comment: can you show a screen of the postman request? form-data is different from x-www-form-urlencode, headers would need setting etc etc

Comment: also `req.body` is not defined in a GET request

Comment: @LawrenceCherone please have a look

Comment: @LawrenceCherone also tried req.q, not working.

Comment: `req.body` doesn't exist in a GET request only PUT and POST, change it to `app.post(` or pass a url param like `/locations?q=delhi%20ncr` which then it will be in `req.query.q`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I changed it app.post() and then req.query is {}

Comment: Don't use app.post @Devang , you are retrieving data not posting data. You can improve by avoiding use of body and pass in the parameters in URL.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use body-parser npm module to parse the body. Are you using it ? Also set the extended urlencoded option to true.

Update:

Since now screenshot is attached, I see that you are using raw JSON as body in POSTMAN,

So use app.use(express.json());

Or app.use(body-parser.json()

Also, GET request generally pass parameters in URL, so maybe you can avoid using the body. Use a POST request only if you want to create new data , it is not to return data based on parameters passed to the endpoint.

Comment: you may have answered a tad too early `app.get(...`

Comment: Yes, Might be. Changing/ using  the settings in Postman in a wrong way also creates an empty object, that's a valid point you have mentioned @Lawrence . And GET request might have a body, just that it is never used .